# JSON request returns two responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

In my rails app I have an `Item` model which has many `Versions`. My controller has a `versions` action.

```
def versions
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @item.versions }
  end
end
```

Whenever I request versions, some items return them successfully and some don't. But when I go into the console, I can get the versions of all items with no problem.

Successful (returns JSON array of versions):

```
Started GET "/api/versions/4.json?"
Processing by ItemsController#versions as JSON
Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 19.8ms)
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /api/versions/4.json?] miss
heroku[router]: GET x.x.com/api/versions/4.json? dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=113ms status=200 bytes=831
```

Not successful (returns two responses, both status 200, no JSON data):

```
Started GET "/api/versions/1.json?"
Processing by ItemsController#versions as JSON
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 200 OK in 249ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 162.9ms)
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /api/versions/1.json?] miss
heroku[router]: GET x.x.com/api/versions/1.json? dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=257ms status=200 bytes=3540
```

Any idea what could cause this? I don't know how to log SQL on Heroku so I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually an error on the client side. On iOS I was handling the returned data in `connection:didReceiveData:`, which (when returning large chunks of data) is called numerous times with partial results. To fix it, I instead concatenated all the partial results in that callback and handled the data in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. Stupid mistake, not related to Heroku or Rails.

Thanks for the help Craig.

Answer (score 2):

Re your SQL logging: Enable statement logging by issuing the SQL `SET log_statement='all';` when you open each connection. Then examine the Heroku logs for Pg to see what's happening.

```
heroku logs --ps postgres
```

See:

- [Heroku's documentation on their PostgreSQL support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)
- [Heroku's logging documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)
- [a Google search for: how to log SQL on Heroku](http://google.com/search?q=how+to+log+SQL+on+Heroku)

This won't log query *results*, only query text, query parameters, and error/success.

To handle result logging you'll need to do it in your application; just print messages to stderr and Heroku will add them to the application logs so you can get them via `heroku logs`.

Your current code looks dodgy anyway. Looping over a result set and emitting json feels wrong:

- It isn't explicitly clear that there can only be one result and thus only emit one json block; and
- If there are no results, no json is emitted

Instead, save the result of the find - if any - to a variable. Then handle missing results properly: in a RESTful API you'd probably report HTTP status `404 Not Found`; in a more RPC-style API you'd return an empty JSON document or a JSON document with a "not found" flag of some kind and report HTTP status `200 OK`.